# get selective details from a line in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

My line is: `/dev/xvdb1: UUID="5950368c-7bf0-45f6-a2b7-d53d3f3bcfa7" TYPE="ext4"`

Can some one give me the unix command to get

*UUID="5950368c-7bf0-45f6-a2b7-d53d3f3bcfa7"*

from this whole line, the command should be such that no matter what lies before and after the needed line that is , *UUID="5950368c-7bf0-45f6-a2b7-d53d3f3bcfa7"*, I should get only this much in the output...

Thanks

Comment: That looks like `blkid` output - if so, it may be simpler to use its `-s` option: `blkid /dev/xvdb1 -s UUID -o value`.

Comment: Wht have you tried???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without quotes:

```
<your-command>| grep -oP 'UUID="\K[^"]+' 
5950368c-7bf0-45f6-a2b7-d53d3f3bcfa7
```

With Quotes:

```
<your-command>|grep -oP 'UUID=".*?"' 
UUID="5950368c-7bf0-45f6-a2b7-d53d3f3bcfa7"
```

Note:

`.*?"` : This means zero or more character till "*nearest*" double quotes.

Comment: Please have courtsy to explain why you downvoted, is there anything wrong any scope of imporvement ?

Answer (score -1):

Using the [`cut` command](https://ss64.com/bash/cut.html) is one option:

```
$ a='/dev/xvdb1: UUID="5950368c-7bf0-45f6-a2b7-d53d3f3bcfa7" TYPE="ext4"'
$ echo $a | cut -d ' ' -f 2
UUID="5950368c-7bf0-45f6-a2b7-d53d3f3bcfa7"
```

`-d ' '` tells `cut` to use space as delimiter, and `-f 2` tells to return the second part.

Comment: *Thank you* unknown user for the downvote, it's really *constructive and motivating.* Would you be so kind to help me understand why my answer deserves a downvote? What's wrong with it? How can I improve it?